# Item collection count - Racket/Sceme

Tags: count, functional-programming, scheme, racket, mud

I am in the process of designing a small MUD game using racket. In my game, gems which are collected by the player are used to bribe guards. Currently if the player possesses more than 1 gem, the game will not let them bribe a guard.

Here is the relevant code:

```
;; This code processes the bribe command.
((equal? cmd 'bribe)
 (if (get-area-item rid 'guard)
     (begin
       (if (eq? (user-attribute 'gem) 1)
           (begin
             (hash-table-set! areasdb rid (replace-area-item (get-area rid) 'guard '(guard #f)))
             (user-add-value 'gem -1))
           (describe 'bribe-no-gem))
       (describe 'bribe))
     (describe 'bribe-blank)))
```

Comment: I will say—if you're doing this in Racket, your code is a little wonky for Racket code. Especially the `require`, which should at the very least be `(require srfi/69)` instead of using the full `lib` syntax. If you're writing pure Scheme, though, you might want to use `#lang r5rs` instead of `#lang racket`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `(eq? (user-attribute 'gem) 1)` to this, instead:

```
(>= (user-attribute 'gem) 1)
```

By the way, don't use `eq?` to compare numbers. Use `=` or (if you need to compare against generic objects) `eqv?`.

---

The OP asked how to suppress the `bribe` message if there are no gems. Here's how it might be done (I'm going for minimal changes to existing code, not for best style):

```
((equal? cmd 'bribe)
 (if (get-area-item rid 'guard)
     (if (>= (user-attribute 'gem) 1)
         (begin
           (hash-table-set! areasdb rid (replace-area-item (get-area rid) 'guard '(guard #f)))
           (user-add-value 'gem -1)
           (describe 'bribe))
         (describe 'bribe-no-gem))
     (describe 'bribe-blank)))
```

By the way, if the only reason you're using `(describe 'bribe-blank)` is because `if` requires an `else` branch, you can use `when` instead, like so:

```
((equal? cmd 'bribe)
 (when (get-area-item rid 'guard)
   (if (>= (user-attribute 'gem) 1)
       (begin
         (hash-table-set! areasdb rid (replace-area-item (get-area rid) 'guard '(guard #f)))
         (user-add-value 'gem -1)
         (describe 'bribe))
       (describe 'bribe-no-gem))))
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much for your help. One more question, do you know how I might only display the "You have no gems to bribe the guard with!" if the user has no gems? Currently it gets printed with "You search yourself for a gem..." following after it, which doesnt make sense :(

Comment: Lemme reformat your code (only the first one; don't have time to reformat your second one) and see if the method is obvious. :-D

Comment: @JamesPatterson Updated my post to answer your new question.